# How to add dependency between two picklist fields in VF page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to add dependency between two picklist fields PickA and PickB. PickA has options (1,2,3) and PickB has options(x,y,z). So when 1 is selected in PickA, X should be automatically populated on PickB.

And also user can manually select Y or Z for PickA-1.

I cannot add input field because I am restricting some picklist values.
I tried the below code.. when I checked debugs PickA is null

**Class :**

```
String pickA {get;set}
String pickB {get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> getPickListValue()
    {

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.PickA__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
        {
            if( f.getValue() != '4' && f.getValue() != '5' )
            {

                options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
            }
        }
        return options;
    }

    List<SelectOption> PPOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    public void dropdown() {
    System.debug('Debug' + pickA);
        if(pickA == '1'){
          PPOptions.add(new SelectOption('X','X'));
          }
          else if(pickA == '2'){

           PPOptions.add(new SelectOption('Y','Y'));
        }    
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getPPPickLstValue()
    {        
        return PPOptions;
    }
```

**Page :**

```
<apex:selectList title="PickList1" size="1" value="{!pickA}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!PickListValue}" />
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pId" action="{!dropdown}"/>
</apex:selectList>                   
<apex:outputPanel id="pId">
    <apex:selectList title="PickList2" size="1" value="{!pickB}" >                          
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!PPPickLstValue}" />
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: The `<apex:inputField>` tag will do the dependency for you if you just configure a standard dependency...

Comment: I cannot use <apex:inputfield>  as i don't want to show all options in pickA

Comment: Check out [dependent picklists](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_dependent_fields.htm&type=0).